# Bug when viewing data from SQL Server in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server, qgis-2

I'm having an issue with viewing data in QGIS 2 based on a spatial query in SQL Server 2008 R2.

The data appears to load, polygons appear and I can add thematic shading based on data.

However when I view the attribute table for the layer in QGIS, it seems like the same value is being replicated over and over again.

[image: QGIS Data Screengrab]

If I add labels, only one label appears despite there being multiple features with different attributes in the original SQL Spatial query.

[image: QGIS Labels Screengrab]

When I export the layer to a shapefile and open it in QGIS, all the data appears correctly and labelling works without any problem.

[image]

Why is the layer imported from SQL Server behaving so strangely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS must have a unique key column in order to track features.  If you are missing that you will get this behavior.

You can do something like this for your view:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS Row, MS0A01CD, count
```

Comment: Ah thanks! The MSOA01CD field is unique but I see that the key must be numeric.

Comment: Yes only numeric keys at the moment.